# ASP.NET core controller serialize DateTime without time

Tags: c#, .net-core

I would like to format output from `DateTime` when there is no time part as `yyyy-MM-dd` i.s.o. `yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00` default in my case.

The controller API is :

```
[HttpGet("date")]
public async Task<DateTime> GetDateAsync(Date)
{
    // dummy code
    return DateTime.Now.Date;
}
```

In Swagger the output is seen as `yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00`

I suppose this is due to
`internal const string DefaultDateFormatString = @"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.FFFFFFFK";` in `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings`

But I want it to be like `yyyy-MM-dd` where the time part is not there:

```
if (value is DateTime d) 
{
    if (d.TotalSeconds == 0) 
    {
        writer.WriteValue(d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    }
}
```

So I would like to know how to customize the serialization under the above condition and then configure that at startup.

This only for data output from the controllers.

I am  using `ASP.NET 3.1` and using `Newtonsoft.Json`

Thanks

Comment: If you're using .NET 6 then use `DateOnly` instead of `DateTime`

Comment: What version of asp.net core are you using? Are what serializer (newtonsoft or system.text.json)?

Comment: you have to post the whole action, if you need some help

Comment: Try writer.WriteValue(d.Date.ToString("o")); It would produce yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00

Comment: I tried using DateOnly but it is  not  getting serialized to a string like 2021-12-29 which is what I would want. It is  providing the JSON representation of the struct. Do I need to hookup a serializer at startup that will convert all DateOnly types from any controller to the above string format? @DavidG

Comment: The issue is still open https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/53539

Comment: The `DateTime` object doesn't contain a human-readable date format. It's simply a `long` value (`Ticks`). It's therefore impossible to apply a format to it. You can, however, change how your serializer formats dates when it converts them to `string` during the serialization process.

Comment: DateTime doesn' t have any format, it is just a long number.  You can only see format when you convert  the date to a string. So if you want a special format your api should return  a string, not a DateTime. And any serializer will keep a string as it is .

Comment: how about using a string to hold the value and use `date.ToShortDateString()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a converter and hooked it up at start-up:

```
//...
AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new JsonDateOnlyConverter());
            })



public class JsonDateOnlyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(DateTime)  || objectType == typeof(DateTime?));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        var t = token.ToString();
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Date )
        {
            return token.ToObject<DateTime>();
        }
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.String)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(t) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t))
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (DateTime.TryParse(t, out var val))
            {
                return val;
            }
        }
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Null && (objectType == typeof(DateTime?) || objectType == typeof(DateTime)))
        {
            return null;
        }
        throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected token type: " + t);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is DateTime d)
        {
            if (d.Date.Ticks == d.Ticks)
            {
                writer.WriteValue(d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```